# How to make field names of a custom database table show up in the Views UI

Tags: views

I want to create a view using a table that is already present in the database, I used the hooks_views_data function to describe the tables and its fields. While creating a new view I can see my custom table listed in the view's selection option, but when I use the custom table I don't see the field name for my table instead I see " Array: Array (Array)" in the field selection option.

Database:

```
                                    Table "chado.biomaterial_value"
          Column        |  Type  |                               Modifiers                                
---------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------               ---------------------
          name                | text   | 
          cultivar            | text   | 
          age                 | text   | 
          tissue              | text   | 
          treatment           | text   | 
          phenotype           | text   | 
          developmental_stage | text   | 
          source              | text   | 
          bio_val_id          | bigint | not null default nextval('biomaterial_value_bio_val_id_seq'::regclass)
     Indexes:
     "biomaterial_value_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (bio_val_id)
```

Things that I have implemented: 
bioviews.info

```
name = Bio_Views
description = Custom module For learning views coding
core=7.x
version=VERSION
dependencies[] = views
```

bioviews.module

```
<?php
function bioviews_views_api() {
return array(
    'api' => '3.0-alpha1',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module','bioviews'). '/views',
);
}
```

views/bioviews.views.inc:

```
 <?php

  /**
  * @file
  * Views integration for the mydons custom module
  */

 /**
  * Implements hook_views_data()
  *
  */
  function bioviews_views_data() {
     $data = array();

      // Table name is "biomaterial_value".
      $data['biomaterial_value']['table']['group'] = t('Biomaterial');

      $data['biomaterial_value']['table']['base'] = array(
           'field' => 'bio_val_id',  //Primary key
           'title' => 'biomaterial_value custom table',
           'help' => 'biomaterial_value custom database table'  
         );

   // Description of name field

    $data['biomaterial_value']['name'] = array(
         'title' => t('NAME'), 
         'help' => t('biomaterial_val name field'), 
         'field' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_field', 
            'click sortable' => TRUE,
         ), 
         'sort' => array(
             'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
          ), 
         'filter' => array(
              'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
           ), 
         'argument' => array(
              'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_string',
          ),
       );

  // Description of cultivar field

  $data['biomaterial_value']['cultivar'] = array(
      'title' => t('CULTIVAR'), 
      'help' => t('biomaterial_val cultivar field'), 
      'field' => array(
         'handler' => 'views_handler_field', 
         'click sortable' => TRUE,
       ), 
       'sort' => array(
       'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
    ), 
   'filter' => array(
       'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
   ), 
   'argument' => array(
       'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_string',
  ),
);

 // Description of the age field

  $data['biomaterial_value']['age'] = array(
      'title' => t('AGE'),
      'help' => t('biomaterial_val age field'),
      'field' => array(
          'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
          'click sortable' => TRUE,
        ),
       'sort' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
        ),
        'filter' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
         ),
        'argument' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_string',
         ),
      );

   //Description of the tissue field

   $data['biomaterial_value']['tissue'] = array(
       'title' => t('TISSUE'), 
       'help' => t('biomaterial_val tissue field.'), 
       'field' => array(
       'handler' => 'views_handler_field', 
       'click sortable' => TRUE,
       ), 
       'sort' => array(
         'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
        ), 
        'filter' => array(
          'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
       ), 
        'argument' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_string',
        ),
     );

    // Description of the treatment field

    $data['biomaterial_value']['treatment'] = array(
        'title' => t('TREATMENT'), 
        'help' => t('biomaterial_val treatment field.'), 
        'field' => array(
           'handler' => 'views_handler_field', 
          'click sortable' => TRUE,
        ), 
        'sort' => array(
           'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
         ), 
         'filter' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
          ), 
         'argument' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_string',
         ),
     );

    // Description of the phenotype field

    $data['biomaterial_value']['phenotype'] = array(
         'title' => t('PHENOTYPE'), 
         'help' => t('phenotype field.'), 
         'field' => array(
             'handler' => 'views_handler_field', 
             'click sortable' => TRUE,
          ), 
          'sort' => array(
              'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
           ), 
          'filter' => array(
              'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
            ), 
            'argument' => array(
                'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_string',
            ),
       );

      // Description of the developmental_stage

       $data['biomaterial_value']['developmental_stage'] = array(
            'title' => t('DEVELOPMENT STAGE'),       
             'help' => t('phenotype field.'),        
             'field' => array(
                'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
                'click sortable' => TRUE,
            ),
            'sort' => array(
              'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
            ),
            'filter' => array(
              'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
            ),
           'argument' => array(
              'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_string',
             ),
         );

     // Description of the source field

      $data['biomaterial_value']['source'] = array(
          'title' => t('SOURCE'),       
          'help' => t('phenotype field.'),        
          'field' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
            'click sortable' => TRUE,
          ),
          'sort' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
          ),
          'filter' => array(
             'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
           ),
           'argument' => array(
              'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_string',
           ),
      );

      // Description of bio_val_id.
       $data['biomaterial_value']['bio_val_id'] = array(
         'title' => t('ID'),
         'help' => t('biomaterial_value ID field'),
         // Is field sortable TRUE.
         'field' => array(
             'click sortable' => TRUE,
          ),
         // Filter handler for filtering records.
        'filter' => array(
           'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_numeric'
        ),
        'sort' => array(
          'handler' => 'views_handler_sort'
        )
    );

     return $data;

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your nesting isn't quite right in [`hook_views_data`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7). You have `'base'` incorrectly nested under `'group`'

Try something like:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_data()
 *
 */
function bioviews_views_data() {

  $data = array();

  // Assumes table name is "biomaterial_value".
  $data['biomaterial_value']['table']['group'] = t('Biomaterial');

  $data['biomaterial_value']['table']['base'] = array(
    'field' => 'bio_val_id',  //Primary key
    'title' => 'biomaterial_value custom table',
    'help' => 'biomaterial_value custom database table'  
  );

  // Description of bio_val_id.
  $data['biomaterial_value']['bio_val_id'] = array(  
    'title' => t('ID'),
    'help' => t('biomaterial_value ID field'),
    // Is field sortable TRUE.
    'field' => array(
      'click sortable' => TRUE,  
    ),
    // Filter handler for filtering records.
    'filter' => array(
       'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_numeric'   
    ),  
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort'       
    )
  );

  /* ... Add other fields ... */
  // $data['biomaterial_value']['field_name'] = array();

  return $data;

}
```

Also, as an aside, remove

```
files[] = bioviews.module
files[] = views/bioviews.views.inc
```

From `bioviews.info`. [files[]](https://www.drupal.org/node/542202#files) is autoloading for OO classes.

Comment: :Thanks for the suggesting the changes.I updated the code as you suggested. I still have the following error: 
Fields
Broken/missing handler (Broken handler biomaterial_value.name)

Comment: You're welcome. It looks like you're using PGSQL, "name" is a reserved keyword which is probably causing that error ( e.g: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html ). The easiest solution would be to rename that column.

Comment: David:Thanks again. Renaming fixed the broken handler error. Now when I select fields for my view I can only see ID and the biomaterial_name field (renamed name->biomaterial_name). There are selection options with  ':Array' as the value, but not the actual field name.